# Let $E$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$. If $U$ is any open set such that $x \in U$, then $E \cap U$ and $E^C \cap U$ are nonempty. Prove the following:

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

Let $E$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and consider a point $x \in R^d$. If $U$ is any open set such that $x \in U$, then $E \cap U$ and $E^C \cap U$ are nonempty. Prove that there exist points $x_n \in E$ and $y_n \in E^C$ such that $x_n\rightarrow x$ and $y_n\rightarrow x$.

I don't know how to do this problem at all. It seems fairly simple but I am very bad at proofs. Any help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the given statement to open balls $U_n=B(x, \frac{1}{n}) = \{y\in\mathbb{R}^n \mid \|y-x\|<\frac{1}{n}\}$.

Since, for every $n$, $E\cap U_n$ is nonempty you can chose some $x_n\in E\cap U_n$. Then $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $E$ and $\|x_n-x\| < \frac{1}{n} \implies x_n \to x$.

For $E^C$ do the same.